# SIlverligh Client WCF routing performance

Tags: wcf, silverlight, routes

I am experiencing a strange issue in my browser hosted silverlight application.  Call are made to a WCF routing service hosted in on IIS 7. The routing service then switches the protocol to nettcp and routes the request to another WCF service on our application server. This second service is hosted in a windows service. What I am noticing is that when a client on one machine invokes a long running request other users on the network cannot even get smaller requests serviced till the long running request returns.  Has anyone experienced this or does anyone know what can be causing this?

Comment: What is the service's instance mode? See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734715.aspx) for details.

Comment: Instance mode is Percall. I suspect it has something to do with the WCF Router.